# Generating a file with Tag or Branch Name in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I need in my source code to have a text file which contains the current Tag and Branch name.
Generally I want it for browsers "cache killer", I can read this file and append it to every script/css call.
for example: `<script src='file.js?v=1.0'></script>`  the `1.0` will be coming from this generated config file.
I am working in PHP and C# So I need this kind of functionality built in the source control.
Is it possible? I dont want to do it manually, to risky.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`hg log -r. --template='{branch}-{latesttag}'` would give you the branchname of the currently checked-out revision and the last tag preceeding it in its list of ancestors. Either use that call to hg directly or write it to a config file.

See `hg help templates` and maybe also `hg help revsets`